# How do I combine the controls from 2 or more C++ MFC OCXs into 1 OCX?

Tags: html, mfc, ocx

It has been decreed that we will merged several (C++) OCXs, all of which use MFC as a static library, into 1 OCX, to save the download overhead of multiple copies of C runtime.  Management is afraid that the shared DLL setting may cause an installation problem on some version of windows.  I am unwilling to play "you bet your job" that they are wrong.

I have merged 2, by turning 1 into a static library and linking it into the other and adding the linked type library as a resource.  I am attempting to load the linked control into an ASPX , by its guid.  IE finds the merged OCX (because I modified the registry). The combined OCX loads, but the linked control does not.

To FORCE it to load, I manually create a new instance in the OCX "application" code.
Now, it won't receive commands from IE or send events.  Creating the linked control's frame fails, but the LastError is 0.

I've tried other approaches to merge the controls; this is the first one to build and register.

How do I combine the controls from 2 or more OCXen into 1?
How can I get some diagnostic information about my linked control's failure to create its frame?
What am I missing?